# Mysql: how to get the mysql status info just using one command

Tags: mysql, linux

I have installed mysql-server on ubuntu. If I want to know the status of the mysql, I need to type 'mysql -u root -p' in the command line, and then I need to type the password to enter the mysql interaction mode, finally in the interaction mode I need to type 'show status' and I can see the info. Now my question is, is there any method doesn't need to enter the mysql interaction mode, just type one command in the command line and get the mysql status info?

Comment: this question might be better suited for http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: (if **mysqladmin status** not good enough for you) you can build  a script ( depending on your OS ) and run it everytime you need to check status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
mysql -p'password' -e "SHOW STATUS"
```

Where `-e` flag is:

> -e, --execute=name  Execute command and quit. (Disables --force and history file.)

If you don't want to use password as of mysql [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/password-security-user.html) you can store your password in an option file (Note to change permissions respectively):

> Store your password in an option file. For example, on Unix, you can list your password in the [client] section of the .my.cnf file in your home directory:

```
[client]
password=your_pass
```

So finally you have to run:

```
mysql -e "SHOW STATUS"
```